# SQL Server Reporting Services - Average Values for the row

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix that produces data like below:

```
ID | Name | Term1 | Term2
01 | RDA  | 2.9   | 3.9
02 | RDA  | 3.2   | 3.5
```

I want to have a column at the end of the tablix that averages the values for each row.

I've tried the following:

```
 =(Sum(CDec(Fields!term1.Value),"DataSet1") + 
     Sum(CDec(Fields!term2.Value),"DataSet1"))/2
```

However it adds all the values for (2.9 , 3.9, 3.2 and 3.5) rather than just for that row which would be 2.9 + 3.9 /2.

Is it possible to calculate the average for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replicated your data and your report using the following and it performs the `sum()` as it should:

```
=(sum(cdec(Fields!TERM1.Value)) + sum(cdec(Fields!TERM2.Value))) / 2
```

I removed the `,"DataSet1"` from the calculation. This adds a scope to the data, when scope is applied it aggregates for the entire dataset - from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155830%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> Scope (String)
>
> The name of a dataset, grouping, or data region that
>   contains the report items to which to apply the aggregate function. If
>   Scope is specified, the aggregate function applies to all data in the
>   dataset, grouping, or data region. All group expressions for the
>   specified scope must contain simple field references. For more
>   information about the Scope parameter, see Using Report Functions in
>   Expressions (Reporting Services).

Comment: Brilliant thank you - I feel stupid for missing out the obvious.